# Is there a way to tell R that the file I refer to in a connection is a csv2?

Tags: r, file, decimal, sqldf

I have a huge file (csv2) from which I'm selecting 1000 observations using the command sqldf(). Specifically, I use the following code:

```
f<-file("C:/Users/myfile.csv")
df<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT Draw 
           FROM f  
           ORDER BY RANDOM(*) 
           LIMIT 1000", 
         file.format = list(header = TRUE, sep=";", dec=","))

df<-sqldf("SELECT * FROM f 
           WHERE Draw IN df",
        file.format = list(header = TRUE, sep=";", dec=","))
```

The problem is that R doesn't seem to recognize that the file in the connection is a csv2 and the data in the resulting data frame are classified as text because the commas for the decimal are not transformed in dots. Do you know if there is a way to fix the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: As requested at the top of the r tag page please provide a reproducible example. In particular, no one other than you can run this since the question does not have a sample file to try it with.  The first few lines should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading directly from a file, then you should use `read.csv2.sql` eg:

```
  write.csv2(iris, "iris.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  read.csv2.sql("iris.csv", dec = ',', sep = ';',
                 sql = "select * from file
                        where Species = 'setosa' 
                        limit 10")
```

Note that for `csv2` the default separator is `;` hence no need of specifying it. But included it just in case

Comment: dec= is not a supported argument but it automatically translates commas to dots.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example offered by Onyambu we can use `fread` from pkg:data.table because it allows system-level filtering via `grep` or grepl.

```
 filt <- data.table::fread(cmd= paste("grep", "1,4", "iris.csv"), dec=",")
str(filt)
#======================
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  21 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1: num  5.1 4.9 5 4.6 4.4 4.8 5.1 5.2 5.5 4.9 ...
 $ V2: num  3.5 3 3.6 3.4 2.9 3 3.5 3.4 4.2 3.6 ...
 $ V3: num  1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 1.4 ...
 $ V4: num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ V5: chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

The `grepl` function was not present on my Linux box, but `grep` acts the same as I have seen others doing with `grepl` (on Windows with Cygwin).

Comment: Isn't this grep the unix one? I mean one has to have the grep command ie when you open the cmd and type `grep` it should run. like awk, perl, sed etc commands??

Comment: Yes. It's the Unix system program. Many of the worked example of console mediated actions use sed or awk.